# Django rest framework error AssertionError `child` is a required argument

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

when developing my application I ran into a problem

```
AssertionError at /api/update/
`child` is a required argument.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://45.56.80.77/api/update/?token=1234567&ifloorplan=2
Django Version: 3.0.6
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
`child` is a required argument.
Exception Location: /root/Env/ifloorplan/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py in __init__, line 591
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['.',
 '',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/root/Env/ifloorplan/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 1 Jun 2020 07:18:31 +0000
```

that is, I tried to update and create in the database a record of this kind

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "level": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "plan_level": {
                    "img": null,
                    "img_height": null,
                    "img_width": null,
                    "position_x": null,
                    "position_y": null,
                    "level": null
                },
                "images": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "cam": [
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "ken_burns": {
                                    "effect": null,
                                    "start_pos_x": null,
                                    "start_pos_y": null,
                                    "finish_pos_x": null,
                                    "finish_pos_y": null,
                                    "start_width": null,
                                    "start_height": null,
                                    "finish_width": null,
                                    "finish_height": null,
                                    "cam": null
                                },
                                "rotation": 0.34,
                                "pos_x": 21.0,
                                "pos_y": 234.0,
                                "width": 1234.0,
                                "height": 234.0,
                                "img": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "ken_burns": {
                                    "effect": null,
                                    "start_pos_x": null,
                                    "start_pos_y": null,
                                    "finish_pos_x": null,
                                    "finish_pos_y": null,
                                    "start_width": null,
                                    "start_height": null,
                                    "finish_width": null,
                                    "finish_height": null,
                                    "cam": null
                                },
                                "rotation": 4.0,
                                "pos_x": 354.0,
                                "pos_y": 345.0,
                                "width": 345.0,
                                "height": 345.0,
                                "img": 2
                            }
                        ],
                        "img": "/media/ifloorplans_source/test.jpg",
                        "level": 2
                    }
                ],
                "tabLabel": "1 st",
                "plan": 2
            }
        ],
        "textColor": "WQ2123",
        "bgColor": "SA2132",
        "camColor": "CV1234",
        "author": 14
    }
]
```

here is my serializer.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import (
    IFloorPlan,
    Level,
    PlanImg,
    Image,
    Cam,
    KenBurns,

)
from rest_framework import serializers


class KenBurnsSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    # plan = IFloorPlanSerializer(required=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        predictions = [KenBurns(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return KenBurns.objects.bulk_create(predictions)

    class Meta:
        model = KenBurns
        fields = '__all__'


class CamSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    ken_burns = KenBurnsSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        predictions = [Cam(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return Cam.objects.bulk_create(predictions)



    class Meta:
        model = Cam
        fields = '__all__'



class ImageSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    cam = CamSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        predictions = [Image(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return Image.objects.bulk_create(predictions)


    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = '__all__'


class PlanImgSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    # plan = IFloorPlanSerializer(required=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        predictions = [PlanImg(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return PlanImg.objects.bulk_create(predictions)

    class Meta:
        model = PlanImg
        fields = '__all__'


class LevelSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    plan_level = PlanImgSerializer()
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass

    def create(self, validated_data):
        predictions = [Level(**item) for item in validated_data]
        return Level.objects.bulk_create(predictions)

    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = '__all__'

class IFloorPlanSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    level = LevelSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        list_serializer_class = LevelSerializer
        model = IFloorPlan
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import IFloorPlanSerializer
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import IFloorPlan
from public.models import ApiToken
# Create your views here.


@api_view(['GET', ])
def get_ifloorplan(request):
    if "token" in request.GET and "ifloorplan" in request.GET:
        token_obj = ApiToken.objects.filter(token=request.GET["token"])
        if token_obj:
            plans = IFloorPlan.objects.filter(id=request.GET["ifloorplan"])
            serializer = IFloorPlanSerializer(plans, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid token"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid GET parameter"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@api_view(['PUT', 'GET',])
def update_ifloorplan(request):
    if "token" in request.GET and "ifloorplan" in request.GET:
        token_obj = ApiToken.objects.filter(token=request.GET["token"])
        if token_obj:
            plans = IFloorPlan.objects.filter(id=request.GET["ifloorplan"])
            serializer = IFloorPlanSerializer(plans, data=request.data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse({"message": "Update successful"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid token"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid GET parameter"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
def create_ifloorplan(request):
    if "token" in request.GET:
        token_obj = ApiToken.objects.get(token=request.GET["token"])
        if token_obj:
            plans = IFloorPlan(author=token_obj.user)
            serializer = IFloorPlanSerializer(plans, data=request.data, many=True)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse({"message": "Create successful"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid token"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Don't valid GET parameter"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class IFloorPlan(models.Model):
    textColor = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    bgColor = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    camColor = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class Level(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(IFloorPlan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='level', blank=True, null=True)
    tabLabel = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class PlanImg(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='plan_level', blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ifloorplans_source/', blank=True, null=True)
    img_height = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    img_width = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    position_x = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    position_y = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class Image(models.Model):
    level = models.ForeignKey(Level, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images', blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='ifloorplans_source/', blank=True, null=True)

class Cam(models.Model):
    rotation = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pos_x = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    pos_y = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    img = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cam', blank=True, null=True)
    width = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class KenBurns(models.Model):
    cam = models.ForeignKey(Cam, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ken_burns', blank=True, null=True)
    effect = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)
    start_pos_x = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_pos_y = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_pos_x = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_pos_y = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_width = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    start_height = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_width = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    finish_height = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I can’t solve this problem already the second day
At first there was a problem with the inability to update multiple tables. So I decided to use the list serializer to update and create records in the table. I will be glad of any help

Answer (score 5):

A ListSerializer is basically a container for other serializers and can only contain one specific serializer, which is set as it's "child" serializer.

Your `LevelSerializer` extends ListSerializer but does not provide a this child attribute. This is typically not the way to use a ListSerializer - extending it is only needed for very special cases. In the common case, you want create a normal serializer for the `Level` model and set it as a field with `many=True` as argument. This will create a list serializer under the hood as described in [in the documentation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/serializers.md#listserializer)

You make the mistake several times, but this should get you started in the right direction:

```py
class LevelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    class Meta:
        model = Level
        fields = ('plan', 'tabLabel')

class IFloorPlanSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    level = LevelSerializer(many=True)
```

To extend the list serializer and provide a custom update method:

```
class LevelListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    child = LevelSerializer()

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # instance is the queryset, validated_data a list of dicts
        # See [the documentation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/docs/api-guide/serializers.md#customizing-multiple-update) for an example.

class IFloorPlanSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    level = LevelListSerializer()
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, but ran into another problem "Serializers with many=True do not support multiple update by default, only multiple create. For updates it is unclear how to deal with insertions and deletions. If you need to support multiple update, use a `ListSerializer` class and override `.update()` so you can specify the behavior exactly.
" that I had before  error AssertionError `child` is a required argument

Comment: I added this and when receiving data I get an error
```
TypeError at /api/get/
'Level' object is not iterable
```